# initializing static variable in different ways with swift

Tags: swift, xcode

```swift
// Type 1:
class A {
    static let b = ["m":1, "n":2]
}
// Type 2:
class A {
    static let b: [String:Int] = {
         let result = ["m":1, "n":2]
         return result
    }()
}
```

when we access this static variable like A.b["m"], would it be any difference behind the initialization logic? what situation that we need to use type 1 instead of type 2?

Comment: You may have complex scenarios where your static property is something like a `DateFormatter` where you can't set all properties during initialization so you would need to use the closure approach

Comment: variety doesn't always mean a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between the 2 , static variable will take it's assigned value once then the accessing will be same

Type 1 :  is preferred for single line configuration

Type 2 : is used when you need to configure the returned object in a long way e.x : tableView delegate/dataSource/backgroundView where many properties need to be configured

Comment: Thanks Sh_Khan! One more quick question, how do we assign tableview delegate in closure approach? I tried to initialize myTableview variable and assign delegate to itself in Type 2, but I got error say cannot assign value of type (viewController) ->()->viewController to type "UITableViewDelgate?"

Comment: to access `self` inside the closure you need to make it `lazy var`